# Actualizar mir reposiorio remoto Github con los cambios que hice en mi proyecto local

Tags: c#, github

Tengo un solución en visual studio que cuentas con dos proyectos y esta alojodo en un repositorio externo de GitHub. Hw hace poco hice un cambio de código en un arhcivo cs de un proyecto de la misma  solución en mi compuador local.
Las preguntas son las siguientes:

1-Como puedeo hacer la actualización de mi repositorio remoto en github sin tener que subir todo el mi proyecto nuevamente en github. Solamente subir la actualizaciones que es un archivo cs. Si me pueden mostrar con con linea de comnados como hacer las actualizaciones y con github desktop también.

Lo que busco es solo subir esa parte que modifique mi código en un arhivo cs.

Si me pueden asersorar. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Hola te recomiendo que consultes la [documentación de Git](https://git-scm.com/docs) para que comprendas mejores.

Lo que debes hacer es agregar solo el archivo que deseas subir en este caso

git add **nombredearhcivo.cs**

git commit –m “Nueva funcionalidad”

git push -u main nombredeturama

Ya con esto subirías la actualización del archivo a tu repositorio en GitHub

Estos pasos lo podrias realizar desde CMD o el bash de git

Comment: Hola y gracias. Pero primer debo acceder a mi repositorio remoto desde linea de comandos? para poder hacer el add y todo lo demas.

Comment: @PabloDanielAlmada todo depende como estés trabajando, si no tienes tu repositorio localmente, es obvio que debas de clonarlo, haces los cambios y lo actualizas y si  como lo explique es por consola.

Comment: Yo descargue el repositorio que esta en github en mi máquina local con la opcion de download ZIP.  Entonces de esta manera yo ya tengo mi repositorio localmente. La preguntas es como continuo, si asi estoy trabajando.

Comment: Estudia la documentación de Git . Saludos

Comment: Si lo estuvo viendo. De todas maneras como son mas de un archvo que modififique creo que con git add * se puede agregar todos los archivos modificados al indice, y despuedes directamente haria un commit. Si me puede confirmar si es asi. Gracias